# Rewrite jQuery on() to click()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to rewrite this on function to a click function. with the exact same functionality.
I cant use on since I have to use jQuery 1.3

```
$('#citybreak_availability_calendar_widget').on('click', '#CB_SearchButton', function() {
    var iframe = $('#citybreakContent').find('iframe');
    iframe.attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));
    $('#menu ul li a[title="Boka rum"]').click();
    return false;
});
```

And this is what I got:

```
$('#citybreak_availability_calendar_widget #CB_SearchButton').click(function() {
    var iframe = $('#citybreakContent').find('iframe');
    iframe.attr('src', $('#CB_SearchButton').attr('href'));
    $('#menu ul li a[title="Boka rum"]').click();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: and why do you need to do that? did it not work before?

Comment: That's not possible. In your current form, the `.on()` code provides event delegation, which cannot be achieved with `.click()` (at least not out of the box). You could do it with `.delegate()` (I'm assuming that you're trying to avoid `.on()` because you cannot use the latest version of jQuery for some reason).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas yes. I'm using jQuery 1.3 (forgot to write that) and I cant upgrade. How can I rewrite this with delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
$( '#citybreak_availability_calendar_widget' ).click( function ( e ) {
    if ( e.target.id === 'CB_SearchButton' ) {
        // your code
    }
});
```

Since you use version 1.3 which doesn't provide event delegation out-of-the-box, you'll have to implement it manually. The idea is to bind the click handler to the wrapper element, and then - inside the handler - manually check if the event target -  the `e.target` property - is the correct element.

Comment: I tried that but I just saw that delegate came in v1.4 and I'm using 1.3

Comment: @Patrik Oh, I forgot to mention: You'll have to use `e.target` instead of `this` in your code. The `this` value references the widget, and `e.target` references the button.

Answer (score 2):

You're making an event delegation using the .on() function. According to the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/click/), this is not possible with .click(), since it's a shortcut for .bind(), not .delegate().

If you can't use on because your jQuery version is older than 1.7, you can use [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
$('#citybreak_availability_calendar_widget').delegate('#CB_SearchButton', 'click', function() {
    var iframe = $('#citybreakContent').find('iframe');
    iframe.attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));
    $('#menu ul li a[title="Boka rum"]').click();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: delegate() was introduced after version 1.3

Answer (score 1):

Before jQuery had delegation methods such as  live(), delegate() and on() in the core, livequery plugin was heavily utilized. It is well documented on main jQuery site. You may find it useful  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally understand the question, hit this up for delagation:

```
$('body').click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.id === 'CB_SearchButton') {
        var iframe = $('#citybreakContent').find('iframe');
        iframe.attr('src', $('#CB_SearchButton').attr('href'));
        $('#menu ul li a[title="Boka rum"]').click();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: `'#CB_SearchButton'` may be a dynamic element (which would explain why the handler is bound to an ancestor in OP's code).

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help

```
$('#CB_SearchButton').click(function() {
    var iframe = $('#citybreakContent').find('iframe');
    iframe.attr('src', $('#citybreak_availability_calendar_widget').attr('href'));
    $('#menu ul li a[title="Boka rum"]').click();
    return false;
});
```